# Query & Get Facebook posts of public pages

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, http

I am a medical student and like everyone I have been using Facebook for a long time but while I am studying or preparing for exams I tend to quit using Facebook but sometimes that makes me unable to see if new changes are going on university or events about my exams and that make me wonder if I can build an app that can fetch or query some posts of certain pages on Facebook so as an example of what I want to know is that fetch or query as an example my college Facebook pages and fetch the latest posts and display it on my website

Also, I have some experience in programming before and I will put my skills down and I want to know if it helps me to do that

If you do know any or clear path to do it please let me know

My humble Skills: Javascript, HTML, CSS, little Python

Comment: this is where you need to start: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Comment: Your app would need approval from Facebook to read data from public pages - but they likely won't grant it, because what you want is not a supported use case for that feature. Maybe embedding a couple of page plugins, that show the latest feed posts for the pages, would be an option. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: @CBroe is it possible to do it by scraping right?

Comment: That is against Facebook's terms to begin with, and they have measure in place to try and prevent it.